# Symfony framework - module name variable in layout.php

Tags: php, layout, symfony1, model

Which variable I have to use in main layout.php to get current module name?

Comment: Do you mean module name? There isnt any definitive model name because there can be many models in use at any given time.

Comment: :) I mean "module". For ex: http://project.com/module-name. I have to define this "module-name" value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$sf_context

http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_template_shortcuts

Comment: Yeah, I got it myself. Actually must use: $modulename = $sf_context->getModuleName();